# How do you find your facetime call history on iphone/ipad?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, facetime, ipados

This question is mostly tailored for the iPad. When I got to the facetime app on the ipad, I see a list of people I've called and the **last** time I called them, but I can't find anywhere that shows **all** the calls to a certain person. Does anyone know how I can find this information on the ipad?

On the iPhone, there is a similar issue if you go to the facetime app. However, if you go to the phone app, it shows the call history, but there is no phone app on the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

FaceTime history are stored into each device you make FaceTime calls with.

It looks like Apple don't let us see our detailed history, only a global one with recent calls. But there is something we can be 100% sure about : is that **the complete logs are stored somewhere on your device**.

In my case, even with *Handoff* and *Continuity* enabled, FaceTime calls made with one device won't show up on others after hang-up, expect when I make a classic phone call from my Mac *using my iPhone*.

The only way to find it, would be to extract your device's save file and browse it through a third-party-app.